# Is the fgets() string that gets tokenized able to be indexed into characters? :line[0], error: seg

Tags: c, debugging, indexing, segmentation-fault, fgets

After I call `fgets()`, the string I want will only be the first character of line: `line[0]`. When I try to call %s->line[0] I get a segmentation fault. My original assumption is it is in a buffer or bytes. I also think it could be with the pointer pointing to the wrong address. The exact input call to be strtok() will be "!11" and the compare should read the exclamation part and then the numbers after using isdigit().
**Code:**

```
static const char N[] = "!";
...
int main( int argc, char* argv[]) {
...

       while ( ( result = fgets( line, MAX_LEN, stdin ) ) ) {
            if ( line[ 0 ] == '#' ) {
                printf( "%s", line );
            }
            //save line to the history list;
            else {
                cmd = strtok( line, " \n" );
                printf("[0] %s\n",cmd);
               char *newString;
               strcpy(newString,cmd);
               // printf("[0][0] %s \n", newString[0]);

                } else if (strcmp(cmd[0], N) == 0 ) {               //should I use a for loop for history?
                   if ( isdigit(cmd[1])) {
                      printf("Found a digit\n");
                      printf("Executing history command, %i : %s\n", cmd[1], histL[2]);
                   }
                }
```

Comment: Remember that array indexes are *zero* based, so the first character in a string has index `0`.

Comment: cmd[0] is where my code broke, it didn't matter the index. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: O I see in the title...

Comment: You should probably make it correct in the text as well. And note that the values in a string are (most commonly) [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) which means that the character `'1'` has the value `49`.

Comment: I asked the guy who answered about that. I can change that to an int, and am writing another question about calling `printf("command, %i", cmd[1-2]-'0')' to determine the range of numbers found for !11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            } else if (strcmp(cmd[0], N) == 0 ) {               //should I use a for loop for history?
```

This should give you a compiler warning/error. `cmd[0]` is of type `char`. 
Maybe you mean:

```
            } else if (strncmp(cmd, N, 1) == 0 ) {               //should I use a for loop for history?
```

Comment: That handled my question! I was also trying the call the number after the !: !11. Is there a way to split the string to a new variable.

Comment: I recommend using `strtol` in `<stdlib>` to read an integer number from a string (in your case from `&cmd[1]`).

Answer (score 2):

```
char *newString;
strcpy(newString,cmd);
```

here, without allocating memory to `newString`, you're trying to use it in `strcpy()`.

Before using `strcpy()`, you need to allocate memory to `newString` by `malloc()`, like

```
char *newString = malloc(strlen(cmd));
```

---

EDIT:

To address the 1st element of `cmd`, why don't you use the same method as you've used in `line[ 0 ] == '#'`. `strncmp()` with `n = 1` maybe the way, but IMO that's kind of *overkill* for checking a single byte. You can use the comparison `==` directly.

Comment: Thanks, although I wasn't trying to explicitly do that because I was showing my attempt to index. The real problem was getting the first char of cmd to be '!'

Comment: strtok has to be called in the program. It uses a pointer to the first address. It just so happens !11 is one word, most of the other called are calls to the shell (ls folder) ->Reply to edit